# Is it worth it to try to optimize away Nginx regexes?

Tags: regex, performance, nginx

In an Nginx virtual host, I have added these locations, two of which use regular expressions:

```
    location ~ /-/pubsub/subscribe/(.*)$ {
      # subscribe to websocket
    }
    location ~ /-/pubsub/publish/(.*)$ {
      # websocket publish endpoint
    }
    location / {
      # reverse proxy to the application server
    }
```

But instead I can do something like this, to "hide" the regexes?

```
    location /-/pubsub/ {       <-- can be tested without any regex matching
      location ~ subscribe/(.*)$ { ... }
      location ~ publish/(.*)$ { ... }
    }

    location / {
      # reverse proxy
    }
```

It seems to me that this would avoid parsing any regex, for request matching `location /`, because they'll be compared with `location /-/pubsub/` (no regex) instead of `location ~ /-/pubsub/whatever/(.*)$` (with regex), right?

In the same way, I've separated my video uploads from other uploads, because the video uploads make use of a regex:

```
  location /-/uploads/public/video/ {
    location ~ \.(mp4|m4v|m4a)$ {   <-- regex matching for videos only
      mp4;
    }
  }

  location /-/uploads/public/ {
    # all other files: no regex matching needed
  }
```

But I'm not sure if this a-tiny-bit-more-complicated configuration in order to avoid regexes, makes sense. Saving videos in a different folder, just to avoid regexes. Does it ought to be faster? And is it worth the trouble?

Comment: It would be faster if the pattern search happens often; the less overhead usually the better, especially on a web server. Even an optimized regex can make a big difference in terms of efficiency.

Comment: @l'L'l Why will it be faster if the search happens _often_? Will Nginx then optimize it extra much somehow, because it's more important because it's used often? Anyway, each user who visits the website, will download like 100 tiny 25x25 user avatar images (the web app is forum software and the topic list page shows avatars for users in the most recent topics). A CDN would make sense, still I'd like this to be fairly fast also without any CDN.

Comment: Consider for example your pattern [.(mp4|m4v|m4a)](https://regex101.com/r/hK7wW1/1), for every file it takes the regex engine approximately 68 steps each time it does this; on a server with heavy traffic that can add up (cpu overhead mostly). Regex pattern matching is great, however, if there's a more direct route then take it.

Comment: If it could be done in a simple and clear way, then do it, otherwise don't bother, you've got much more inefficiency in your app, I bet. Your examples are quite simple and should be used IMHO

Comment: BTW, `location ~ /-/pubsub/subscribe/(.*)$` should be replaced without regexp at all `location /-/pubsub/subscribe/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some quick tests with `ab` (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html ) and I don't see any difference in performance with the simple regex below, vs. without.

I tested this:

```
location /-/uploads/public/ {
  access_log off;
  alias /opt/debiki/uploads/public/;  <-- serving one 1.4 kb avatar image from here
  autoindex off;
  sendfile on;
  sendfile_max_chunk 2m;
  tcp_nopush on;
  expires 31d;  # later:  expires 365d;

  location ~ \.(mp4|m4v|m4a)$ {   <-- regex
    mp4;
  }
}
```

Commenting out the regex didn't make things faster in a way that I noticed. (did like 5 or 10 samples with regex, and 5 or 10 without, `ab -n50000 -c10` each sample. Results were between 14500 and 15500 req/seq, fairly randomly, both with and without regex)

So my conclusion is that if a `location` regex can be avoided at no cost, then yes. But if avoiding a *simple* regex like `location ~ \.(mp4|m4v|m4a)$` above is a bit complicated, like moving certain files to another directory, then, no, don't do that. It's not worth it.  (More complicated regexs? Then I don't know.)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your use case. Since nginx uses pcre, ultimately you're asking "does pcre use CPU", which is an obvious yes. However, if the majority of the work nginx does is serving file objects and managing remote tcp sockets, then you won't see an impact. If you're doing extremely fast proxying work with nginx (think 50k + connections), my experience is you will ABSOLUTELY experience major performance impact from regex optimizations

To know for certain what your bottleneck is, you need to use a tool like tcpdump and look for time-to-first-data-byte. Also, apache bench is single-threaded and thus very limited in usefulness for high-capacity web servers. If you have to use that tool, I recommend making a cluster of ab instances and add the results up ;)